# Connect four game logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Building a connect four game as my first js project. My game has a background photo of a Connect Four game board and an HTML table on top to hold the tokens. The tokens are images that I will drag onto the board.

So far I have the code(below) which allows me to drag the tokens onto the game board.

```js
var dragYellow = document.getElementById('yellowToken1');
var dragRed = document.getElementById('redToken1');
var dropLoc = [];

function locOnDrop(e) {                 
 e.preventDefault();            
 e.currentTarget.appendChild(        
  document.createElement('img')
 ).src = document.getElementById(    
  e.dataTransfer.getData('key')  
 ).src;
}

gameGrid = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],                         
          [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
          [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
          [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
          [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
          ];

for(var i = 0; i < gameGrid.length; i++){           
     for(var j = 0; j < gameGrid[i].length; j++){        

     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]] = document.getElementById(gameGrid[i][j].toString());
     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]].ondrop = locOnDrop;          
                                                              
     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]].ondragover = function(e) {       
         e.preventDefault();
     }
 }
}
```

There are numerous 'check for winner' examples, but they are all based on games utilizing arrays instead of tables. The closest I found was this question asked in 2012(see below). The best answer suggested was NOT to use DOM transversal, but rather a 2D array. I'm ok with that, but how would I get my table to "communicate with the array? If I'm drag & dropping the pieces into a table how will I connect these moves with the array?

[algorithm connect four javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331169/algorithm-connect-four-javascript)

Not to complicate matters, but for the end result I want to just drop the tokens at the top of each column and let them drop down to the lowest available position just like in the real game. I'm only mentioning this in case affect the answer to my first question.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give us a complete working example?

Comment: not sure how I would do that. The background , gameboard and token images are saved on my computer. I can post the HTML and CSS files as well if that helps?

Comment: here's the HTML

Comment: @JeffS to get best answer here try to add your code at http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/. Then link your code here. As your project is html + js + css you will have no problem. People can help you much more when they can see and run your code

Answer (score 0):

The way you communicate is by making sure (like the answer mentioned) that your table is only JUST a visual representation of your data which in this instance would be stored in a 2D array.

So you should engineer your code so that is doesn't flow

-> from HTML to JS but

-> from JS to HTML

By that I mean instead of thinking how the car should look and then build your engine according to that, figure out how the engine will turn out first and then build your car around it.

In this instance the answer in the other Stack question gives a good pointer for that.

If I was to try to tackle this problem I would (in no particular order):

- Create a function that allows users to "fill" a certain spot
- Function that checks if a specific spot is taken
- Function that check if this newly played move is winning combination
- Function to place a certain token whether red or yellow in a given slot

There might be more that come up and all but this is just to give you an example. You see a lot of the things that are happening here are all calculation or algorithm based which happens inside the JS and there's very few interaction with the actual DOM.

The only one I've listed here is to add a token. You have all the information you need about your game stored in your 2D array for these functions to work.  It is **ONLY** when something needs to be physically modified that your application say to the DOM: "Hey, add a yellow token at this spot" and so on.

Then of course these variously created function These functions can be mapped to your DOM by attaching events handler, etc... but hopefully you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

While you could do something to figure out the position of a given cell in the row, and the position of the row in the table (for example, when you click a TD or the like), the simplest way is probably to actually build the data into the table.

For example, if your HTML table looks like:

```
<tr data-row='1'><td data-column='1'>&nbsp;</td><!-- rest of the cells --></tr>
```

It becomes pretty trivial to use jquery or similar to find the right position that maps to the array info.  For that matter, if each cell has a unique number (as your sample suggests) you could even just have each TD have that info stored as `data-position="12"` or the like and make the query even easier.

In jquery you could just use `$('td[data-position=12]')` to grab the element directly.

Answer (score 0):

per @Alireza Fattahi request

https://jsfiddle.net/lgehrig4/thg468ex/

what my code accomplishes so far
1. visuals (background, gameboard, tokens)
2. Grab player names(2 player only. Not against the computer)
3. Randomly picks a player to start
4. Can drag and drop tokens onto the board

```js
//SETUP
var button = document.getElementById("setStart");
var gameActive = false;


//GRAB PLAYER NAMES / CHOOSE FIRST MOVE /RESET BOARD
function setStart() {

 if (gameActive == false) {
  playerOne = prompt("Player One(yellow) please enter your name");
  playerTwo = prompt("Player Two(red) please enter your name");
  document.getElementById("yellowPlayer").innerHTML = playerOne;
  document.getElementById("redPlayer").innerHTML = playerTwo;
  gameActive = true;
 }
 players = [playerOne, playerTwo];

 if (gameActive == true) {
        first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        alert(players[first] + " you go first");
 }
}

//MOVE TOKENS TO BOARD

var dragYellow = document.getElementById('yellowToken1');
var dragRed = document.getElementById('redToken1');
var dropLoc = [];

function locOnDrop(e) {                 
 e.preventDefault();            
 e.currentTarget.appendChild(        
  document.createElement('img')
 ).src = document.getElementById(    
  e.dataTransfer.getData('key')  
 ).src;
}

gameGrid = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],                            
          [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
          [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
          [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
          [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
          ];

for(var i = 0; i < gameGrid.length; i++){          
     for(var j = 0; j < gameGrid[i].length; j++){       

     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]] = document.getElementById(gameGrid[i][j].toString());
     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]].ondrop = locOnDrop;         
                                             
     dropLoc[gameGrid[i][j]].ondragover = function(e) {      
         e.preventDefault();
     }
 }
}

dragYellow.ondragstart = function(evt) {              
    evt.dataTransfer.setData('key', 'yellowToken1');  

dragRed.ondragstart = function(evt) {                 
    evt.dataTransfer.setData('key', 'redToken1');     
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: url("img/table.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: bottom;
}

#game {
 background: url("img/background1.png");
 position: relative;
 width: 700px;
 height: 700px;
 margin-left: 260px;
 margin-top: 120px;
 /*z-index: -1;*/
}

table {
 position: absolute;
 right: 117px;
 top: 120px;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 z-index: 2;
}

td {
 width: 66px;
 height: 59px;
 text-align: center;
}

#yellow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 220px;
 top: 520px;
 z-index: 3;
}

#red {
 position: absolute;
 width: 130px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 341px;
 top: 520px;
 z-index: 3;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

button {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 1100px;
 top: 700px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: black;
}

/*player one div*/
#playerOne {
 position: relative;
 width: 165px;
 height: 110px;
 left: 1120px;
 top: 475px;
}

/*player two div*/
#playerTwo {
 position: relative;
 width: 165px;
 height: 110px;
 left: 1120px;
 top: 510px;
}

/*player one name*/
#yellowPlayer {
 width: 160px;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: yellow;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 15px;
}

/*player two name*/
#redPlayer {
 width: 160px;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: red;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 15px;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

#playerOneWins {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 margin: auto;
}

#playerTwoWins {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 50px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="connect.css">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Banner -->
 <div id="banner">

 </div>

 <!-- Player One's name and score -->
 <div id="playerOne">
  <div id="yellowPlayer"></div>
  <!-- <input id="yellowPlayer" type="text" name="playerOneName" maxlength="15" value="Player One Name"> -->
  <h3>WINS</h3>
  <div id="playerOneWins">

  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Player Two's name and score -->
 <div id="playerTwo">
  <div id="redPlayer"></div>
  <!-- <input id="redPlayer" type="text" name="playerTwoName" maxlength="15" value="Player Two Name"> -->
  <h3>WINS</h3>
  <div id="playerTwoWins">

  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- New Game /  -->
 <button id="btn" onclick="setStart()">New Game</button>


 <!--Main Board  -->
 <div id="game">
  <table id="gameBoard">
   <tr id="row1">
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
    <td id="3"></td>
    <td id="4"></td>
    <td id="5"></td>
    <td id="6"></td>
    <td id="7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row2">
    <td id="8"></td>
    <td id="9"></td>
    <td id="10"></td>
    <td id="11"></td>
    <td id="12"></td>
    <td id="13"></td>
    <td id="14"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row3">
    <td id="15"></td>
    <td id="16"></td>
    <td id="17"></td>
    <td id="18"></td>
    <td id="19"></td>
    <td id="20"></td>
    <td id="21"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row4">
    <td id="22"></td>
    <td id="23"></td>
    <td id="24"></td>
    <td id="25"></td>
    <td id="26"></td>
    <td id="27"></td>
    <td id="28"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row5">
    <td id="29"></td>
    <td id="30"></td>
    <td id="31"></td>
    <td id="32"></td>
    <td id="33"></td>
    <td id="34"></td>
    <td id="35"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row6">
    <td id="36"></td>
    <td id="37"></td>
    <td id="38"></td>
    <td id="39"></td>
    <td id="40"></td>
    <td id="41"></td>
    <td id="42"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- Mouse Down / Mouse Up event -->
  <div id="yellow">
   <img src="img/yellow.png" id="yellowToken1" class="image" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="red">
   <img src="img/red.png" id="redToken1" class="image" draggable="true" >
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" -->





<script src="connect.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the html there instead of sending an answer